# Which Beer magazines can I get in Europe - Czech Republic?

Tags: beer, magazine

I am looking for reasonable prices for magazines, which can be send over to Czech Republic. I need English written ones and they should be about beers, brewing etc.
Do you know about any good ones not only limited to the USA market?

Comment: I think BYO and zymurgy are basically it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zymurgy ships internationally, also, and now there's an electronic version of it so you don't even have to deal with shipping if you don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

[Brew Your Own](http://www.byo.com/subscribe) ships internationally.

Comment: Yes, I know BYO, but it is not the cheapest solution, however I think the only which is quality. Thanks